# Is it possible to have one big array, and then smaller ones which point to subsections of the larger array, in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I would like to have an array that holds all of my class' parameters in a single array, and then have each of those parameters point to their locations in the large array.

The reason i want to do this is because i'm going to be optimizing a functio nthat's based on said parameters, but the minimization requires all the parameters be inside a single array - i don't want to be copying this array back and forth at every step - i'd rather have the individual parameters point to their locations in the main array. Something like this:

```
class myClass{
  int nVariables;
  public double[] parameters; //length = X * nVarialbes
  public double[] A; //length = X
  public double[] B; //length = X
  public double[] C; //length = X
}
```

where `parameters` is really something like `[a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3]` (where `X==3` in this example) - the number of each parameter is the same here, but i would rather a solution that would allow that to be generic.

This will also allow me to change the elements of `A`, `B`, and `C` and have the array holding them all update too.

I need to have the array holding all the data as a single contiguous array for the optimization, so just doing `parameters = new double[]{A,B,C};` won't work - unless there's a way i can then access that as if it were a single array; my understanding was that a jagged array was not contiguous in memory though, and i'm not familiar enough with rectangular arrays to do what i want here.

Comment: If you're fine with going the `unsafe` route you could do this with pointers and all that stuff, or union-like structs. Though I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with traditional arrays.  Arrays in .NET/CIL begin with an 8-byte header that provides the virtual table and length of the array.  Because of the 8-byte header, it's not feasible to declare an array within another array.

However, this can be done with pointers.  Take the following class:

```
unsafe class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    double[] parameters = new double[9] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private double* p;
    public double* A;
    public double* B;
    public double* C;

    GCHandle _handle;
    public MyClass()
    {
        _handle = GCHandle.Alloc(parameters, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        p = (double*)_handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
        A = p;
        B = (p + 3);
        C = (p + 6);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(", ", parameters.Select(a=>a.ToString()));
    }

    private bool disposedValue = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            _handle.Free();
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    ~MyClass() {
       Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

The constructor creates a fixed pointer to `parameters`, which prevents the garbage collector from moving it in memory.  The pointer, `p`, is the address of the first element of `parameters`.  The class exposes three pointers (A, B, and C) that point to the 0th, 3rd, and 6th elements of the array.

While pointers are not arrays, they are referenced similarly to C arrays.  As a simple driver:

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass mc = new myClass();
    Console.WriteLine(mc.ToString()); // prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    mc.B[2] = 42; // now parameter[5] set to 42
    Console.WriteLine(mc.ToString()); // prints 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 42, 7, 8, 9
}
```

As a caution, this approach is not idiomatic for C#, where unsafe code is [rarely required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx) generally reserved for specialized scenarios.  Using [`ArraySegment<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) or the other approaches suggested are more traditional.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in .NET. An array is not a pointer.

You have to use a type other than array for that. If you want to refer to a subsection of an array you can use the `ArraySegment<T>` type. You also could create a custom `IList<T>` that wraps a section of an array.

Maybe the answer will turn out to be that there is no practical way to achieve what you want. I believe there is work being done to add "slices" to .NET that are able to refer to ranges of memory in the way you want. The work is being done on Github in the corefxlab repo.

Comment: So the answer is, essentially, "use cpp instead" then, at least for the moment?

Comment: I would not say that. The language choice depends on a lot more concerns. I cannot recommend a language because I have a limited view of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a simple helper function that accepts the main array, the functions offset, the length (for checking purposes) and the parameter they want from the functions relative array.

I could see a function like this working:

```
public T GetFunctionParam(T[] mainArray, 
                          int FuncOffset, 
                          int FuncParamCount, 
                          int targetParam)
```

Then you can simply call it inside a function when needed to get a specific parameter

```
var param = GetFunctionParam(mArray, 3, 3, 2)
```

But all types would have to be the same to be in the array, or use inheritance or interfaces.

If the objects in the main array are reference types, you could then create separate arrays for each function, and populate it with the reference to the original object.

Comment: but this doesn't solve the requirement of directly accessing the elements i want to put through the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

how not create a second array that contains the indexes to the primary array?

A call like

```
paramters[A[0]]
```

Then you have the value

Something like:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var mClass = new myClass();

      Console.WriteLine("Before Optimization");
      mClass.PrintParameters();

      mClass.Optimize();

      Console.WriteLine("After Optimization");
      mClass.PrintParameters();

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }

  class myClass
  {
    int nVariables;
    public double[] parameters; //length = X * nVarialbes
    public int[] A; //length = X
    public int[] B; //length = X
    public int[] C; //length = X

    public myClass()
    {
      parameters = new[] {0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};

      A = new[] {0, 1};
      B = new[] {2, 3};
      C = new[] {4, 5};
    }

    public void Optimize()
    {
      //A's need to have b's paramaters added to them
      parameters[A[0]] += parameters[B[0]];
      parameters[A[1]] += parameters[B[1]];

      //C's paramaters get their sign inverted
      parameters[C[0]] *= -1;
      parameters[C[1]] *= -1;
    }

    public void PrintParameters()
    {
      for(int index =0; index < parameters.Length; ++ index)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", index, parameters[index]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to be able to pass the parameters, and arbitrary subsets of the same parameters to the optimization, and have the changes made inside reflected in my object without having to copy the array contents back and forth repeatedly.

Comment: The function arrays in this case 'A' does not contain the values directly, they contain a pointer to the main 'parameter' array.  When the optimizer changes the value 'parameter[A[0]] = 4' the value in the main array changes.  This is using the second array to point to the elements in the primary array, it never holds the actual values specifically.

Comment: this still does not achieve what i want - the optimization takes a contiguous array of the variables which will be changed, not the full array and a list of indices.

Comment: so you are concerned how the parameters are layed out on disk to do your optimizations?  I just don't understand how a contiguous list of index to the array will not work.  Without some context of what "optimizations" you are talking about to help clarify the question.

Comment: not how they are layed out on disc, but i want to be able to pass a subset of the parameters to the optimization without copying them, which would require them to be contiguous in memory.

Comment: With this method you are not coping the elements from the original array to the secondary array.  The secondary array is the "pointer" to the position in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 0; //index for long array
parameters = new double[combinedLength];
double[][] arrays = new double[][]{A,B,C}; //you can do it with 3 "for" loops instead.
for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
    for( int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++){
        parameters[n++] = arrays[i][j];
    }
}
```

This code takes 3 arrays of whatever length and copies them into a single long array.
It's important to note that this is a copy, not a reference, so if you change one, the other will remain unchanged.

If you want one array to affect the others, have A, B, and C, be arrays of Objects with the desired variables inside. Same code should work for assembling the array.
With Objects, the assignment operator doesn't copy the value, but instead assigns a reference.
So parameters[0] is the same object as A[0].

BE CAREFUL with keeping multiple references of the same object, this is a common source of many bugs, memory leaks, and headaches in general.

Comment: this is exactly the situation i'm trying to avoid, i don't think you understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I'll add in another option with unsafe structs, fixed arrays and explicit layout:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
unsafe struct BadSolution
{
    [FieldOffset( 0 )]
    public fixed double Data[3 * 3];

    [FieldOffset( 8 * 0 )]
    public fixed double A[3];
    [FieldOffset( 8 * 3 )]
    public fixed double B[3];
    [FieldOffset( 8 * 6 )]
    public fixed double C[3];
}
```

However, this comes with a bunch of drawbacks, some of which are:

1. It only works for structs, so you'll have to be very careful about how you pass it around (as with any mutable struct).
2. It gives you a very large struct (the array is part of the struct, not a reference).
3. It's fixed - you have to do the layout manually at compile time.
4. They're no longer proper `Array`'s. Any method (such as `Array.Copy` or `Array.Sort` that expects an `Array` will not work.
5. It uses unsafe code.

(of course 4 & 5 applies to the other answers that use unsafe code as well)

So the disadvantages of this are plenty and I wouldn't recommend anyone to go this path. But, it is possible.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of this approach?

Comment: @will Added a few disadvantages.